# split reviews according to words stored in a text file in java using token regex

Tags: java, regex, stanford-nlp

I am using Stanford Pos tagger to tag some reviews. however I need to split reviews into sentences (already done). it is not sufficient for my method I need also to split sentence according to words stored in an external text file (as a database). for example words are the products features or specs and If a single sentence review is describing two different specs I must have as an output (output file) two different line sentences. each spec can begin with # ....
I need the token REGEX that can help split with words in a text file ....

Can you help please ! thank you

Comment: please post some sample data and your attempts..

Comment: First of all thanks for your interaction.

Comment: First of all thanks for your interaction.Concerning data sample we can take for example this iphone6 plus review ;" The iPhone 6 Plus easily fits in the front pocket of my admittedly not-that-tight Levi’s." it is only one sentence review I need to split it  by products features (already stored in a text file as a database). I need to construct some combinations like if there is text and then feature1 then relate the text with feature 1 because it may contain opinion about it etc how can I do this kind of training and build these combinations ...

Comment: Moroever if there are four words and then a feature split the sentence and put it in a new line of output file ......